# Wordpress MU wp_posts table

Tags: multisite

We have wordpress MU and have wp_*_posts tables and wp_posts table.

They both seem to get updated. Why are there 2 sets of tables for posts? I was reading somewhere that each blog is suppose to keep track of their posts.

I also have noticed that wp_*_posts doesn't always have the excerpt. Do you think something is wrong with our install?

Comment: Unrelated to the Question, but are you still using MU or already upgraded to Multisite? :::: Very good reading: http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/

Answer (score 2):

`wp_posts` table will be for the "main" site -- the one from which the network was installed.

`wp_*_posts` will be for other sites in the network -- one set of tables per site.

Excerpts are only saved when a user enters something in the "Excerpt" field in the admin area. If nothing was entered, nothing gets saved and WordPress will dynamically generate an excerpt if you request one. It's fairly normal to have some empty excerpts.